# Can I use the MainCamera Depth in a Shader which runs with a replacement on second Camera in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I am trying to sample the depth of the main camera with _CameraDepthTexture within a replacment shader of a second camera. But this doesn't seem to work, the depth buffer is always 1. The replacment shader is not doing any zwrites. My second camera renders to a rendertexture. I have enabled depthTextureMode for the main camera and disabled it for the secondary camera.

Inside the vertex shader i use o.projPos = ComputeScreenPos(o.pos) to compute screenspace texture sampling coordinates.

The fragmentshader looks like this:

```
float depth = Linear01Depth (tex2Dproj(_CameraDepthTexture, 
UNITY_PROJ_COORD(i.projPos)).r);
half4 c;
c.r = depth;
c.g = depth;
c.b = depth;
c.a = 1;

return c;
```

Should i be able to access the DepthTexture of the MainCamera?

Kind regards

Florian

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" is an awful description for questions.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input, i tried to be more specific.